# generate sequence within group in R

Tags: r, sequence

I am trying to obtain a sequence within category.

My data are:

```
A B 
1 1 
1 2
1 2
1 3
1 3
1 3
1 4
1 4
```

and I want to get variable "c" such as my data look like:

```
A B C
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 3 1
1 3 2
1 3 3
1 4 1
1 4 2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `ave` with `seq_along`:

```
> mydf$C <- with(mydf, ave(A, A, B, FUN = seq_along))
> mydf
  A B C
1 1 1 1
2 1 2 1
3 1 2 2
4 1 3 1
5 1 3 2
6 1 3 3
7 1 4 1
8 1 4 2
```

If your data are already ordered (as they are in this case), you can also use `sequence` with `rle` (`mydf$C <- sequence(rle(do.call(paste, mydf))$lengths)`), but you don't have that limitation with `ave`.

If you're a `data.table` fan, you can make use of `.N` as follows:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, C := sequence(.N), by = c("A", "B")]
DT
#    A B C
# 1: 1 1 1
# 2: 1 2 1
# 3: 1 2 2
# 4: 1 3 1
# 5: 1 3 2
# 6: 1 3 3
# 7: 1 4 1
# 8: 1 4 2
```

Comment: I had a similar problem in my code and I was able to solve this using data.table.  I saw on stackoverflow a lot of other answers recommend using ave () but I'm not entire sure how ave is supposed to work.   Here is a link the r documentation. 
 ave reminds me a lot of lapply and other functions. 
 Could you expand upon the first method? 
 https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/ave