# Reshape in R without aggregation (for example MTurk response strings)

Tags: r, reshape, mechanicalturk

Ordinarily, I'd use a pretty basic long-to-wide reshape for this, but it seems to be dropping my aggregation variables. The setup is I had a job on mechanical Turk that I performed in triplicate---I want MTurk1, Mturk2, MTurk3's answers to be their own variables in the data frame but uniquely id'd by a field I input with the job, so that I can compare them against each other with a function later.

Current Format:

```
> head(mturk)
  AssignmentStatus     Input.id  Input.State  Answer.Q1thing
1         Approved       134231           NY         Myguess
2         Approved       134231           NY         Myguess
3         Approved       134231           NY        BadGuess
4        Submitted       134812           CA         Another
5         Approved       134812           CA         Another
6         Approved       134812           CA         Another
```

I'd like this to become

```
Input.id   Input.State Answer.Q1thing.1 Answer.Q1thing.2 Answer.Q1thing.3  AssignmentStatus.1 AssignmentStatus.2  AssignmentStatus.3
134231              NY          Myguess          Myguess         BadGuess          Approved             Approved            Approved
134812              CA          Another          Another          Another         Submitted             Approved            Approved
```

or ideally, if there's a variable that can redo column names in the operation....

```
Id               State          Answer1          Answer2          Answer3          Status1               Status2             Status3
134231              NY          Myguess          Myguess         BadGuess          Approved             Approved            Approved
134812              CA          Another          Another          Another         Submitted             Approved            Approved

dat <- reshape(mturk, timevar="Answer.Q1thing", idvar=c("Input.id", "Input.state"), direction="wide")
```

This seems to be failing because most reshape long-to-wide functions expect that the variable that becomes wide itself a categorical text-field---that is, this is not a long-to-wide reshape operation because I don't want a variable named "MyGuess" "BadGuess" and "Another", but I want a generic "Answer.X" variable containing these values.  I'm not trying to aggregate in any way, such as mean or sum, just list the value in a new place.

So, two directions for this question:

1. Does this kind of operation have another name?  Is this an unfold, unpivot, uncast or something?
2. How to do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is in a `data.table` <strike>it's a one-liner</strike> can be done as follows:

```
library(data.table)    
mturk.dt <- as.data.table(mturk)

mturk.dt[, as.list(
         rbind(c(Answer.Q1thing, AssignmentStatus))
         )
        , by=list(Id=Input.id, State=Input.State)]
```

Note that the `by` argument handles the name-changing too!

---

If you want to properly name the other columns, use `setnames` after the fact or, more dynamically, using `setattr`  within the `j=..` argument as follows:

#### After the Fact:

```
## Assuming 'res' is the reshaped data.table form above:
## Change the names of the six V1, V2.. columns 
setnames(res, paste0("V", 1:6), c(paste0("Answer", 1:3), paste0("Status", 1:3)))
```

#### Dynamically, in `j=..`

```
## Use `as.data.table` instead of `as.list`, to preserve new names
mturk.dt[, as.data.table(
         rbind(c(
              setattr(Answer.Q1thing,   "names", paste0("Answer", seq(Answer.Q1thing  )))
            , setattr(AssignmentStatus, "names", paste0("Status", seq(AssignmentStatus)))
            ))
         )
        , by=list(Id=Input.id, State=Input.State)]

       Id State Answer1 Answer2  Answer3  Status1  Status2  Status3
1: 134231    NY Myguess Myguess BadGuess Approved Approved Approved
2: 134812    CA Myguess Myguess BadGuess Approved Approved Approved
```

Comment: I don't think that counts as one line :P

Comment: @hadley, sure it does :)  just one very looooooooooooong line

Answer (score 1):

Using `plyr`:

```
res = ddply(dat,.(Input.id,Input.State),
            function(x)unlist(as.character(x$Answer.Q1thing)))
setNames(res,c('Id','State','Answer1','Answer2','Answer3'))
  Id State Answer1 Answer2  Answer3
1 134231    NY Myguess Myguess BadGuess
2 134812    CA Another Another  Another
```

**EDIT**

In case you have fewer than 3 answers:

```
res = ddply(dat,.(Input.id,Input.State),
            function(x)
              {
              xx= unlist(as.character(x$Answer.Q1thing))
              if(length(xx)==3)xx
              else c(xx,rep(NA,3-length(xx)))
            })
```

Comment: First, thanks!  It looks like this is making it unique by state, rather than unique by id + state.  So, I revised the `(Input.id)` to `(Input.id,Input.State)`, but find I'm still getting an error related to `x$Answer.Q1thing`, which is:
`"Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels")) : 
  Results do not have equal lengths
"`

Comment: @Mittenchops I edit my answer. I group by id and state.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like my data has issues---for this and for the excellent answer below, it seems I can't always count on 3 per ID, sometimes there were fewer than 2 answers.

Answer (score 1):

That was super helpful, @Ricardo and @agstudy.  I realized my reshape wasn't working only because it demanded a unique, categorical "timevar".  I think in most cases, you do have a categorical label/factor like this that makes it easy, but it is not much harder to count them, and make the count into a label.

I had a second problem was that my number of answers were not consistent; you both gave good help for that, but I was also able to just generate a counter and then implemented my original long-to-wide.

Where the count was < 3, that is where an Input.id only had 2 Answers, I got NAs for this, which is what I wanted.

So altogether:

```
mturk$idx <- with(mturk, ave(Input.id, Input.id, FUN=seq_along)) # weird!
dat <- reshape(mturk, timevar="idx", idvar=c("Input.id", "Input.state"), direction="wide")
```

I used the syntax for counting sequences within a group that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815088/generate-sequence-within-group-in-r).  This was a little idiosyncratic in the use of the `ave()` function, but seems to crop up in a couple other answers.  Tried `rtl`, too, but had no luck.  Using ave(x,x,seq_along) seems to mostly be a hack to avoid sorting.  It's odd to use this work-around for sequences in groups because clearly both count() and rtl() are effectively creating this sequencing under the hood in a temp variable.

I like the way data.table allows this sequencing better.

Comment: FYI, the `idx` part in data.table:  `mturk.dt[, idx := seq(.N), by=c("Input.id")]`

Comment: Yeah, that's tons clearer.  That's reason alone to switch to data.table, even without the speed boost, and that all the cool kids are doing it.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

[From data.table v1.9.5+](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), `dcast` can handle multiple `value.var` columns, i.e., we can cast multiple columns simultaneously. We can simply do:

```
dt[, id := seq_len(.N), by=Input.id]
dcast(dt, Input.id + Input.State ~ id, 
        value.var=c("AssignmentStatus", "Answer.Q1thing"))
#    Input.id Input.State 1_AssignmentStatus 2_AssignmentStatus 3_AssignmentStatus
# 1:   134231          NY           Approved           Approved           Approved
# 2:   134812          CA          Submitted           Approved           Approved
#    1_Answer.Q1thing 2_Answer.Q1thing 3_Answer.Q1thing
# 1:          Myguess          Myguess         BadGuess
# 2:          Another          Another          Another
```

Or everything together in one line:

```
dcast(dt, Input.id + Input.State ~ dt[, seq_len(.N), by=Input.id]$V1, 
                 value.var=c("AssignmentStatus", "Answer.Q1thing"))
```