# R: Group by Sequence of Rows

Tags: r, sequence

I have a data frame from IMDB that looks like this. It is unfortunately not grouped but I was hoping I can make R group it.

The data look like this:

```
V1                  V2              starts_with
NM: Aarons          Alex            NM
DB: 15 May 1890     Philadelphia    DB
NM: Aarons          Leroy           NM
NM: Aarons          Shawn           NM
DB: 26 March 1989   Jamaica         DB
```

What I would like is for a new column to be added. a sequence based on the combination of the NM & DB. Every time there is a new "NM" there will be a new number:

```
V1                  V2              starts_with     group
NM: Aarons          Alex            NM              1
DB: 15 May 1890     Philadelphia    DB              1
NM: Aarons          Leroy           NM              2
NM: Aarons          Shawn           NM              3
DB: 26 March 1989   Jamaica         DB              3
```

I of course searched SO and saw this [generate sequence within group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815088/generate-sequence-within-group-in-r) but that example was already grouped. My data unfortunately aren't grouped.

Comment: You can do just `cumsum(df$starts_with == "NM")`.

Comment: Given `x <- c('NM', 'DB', 'NM', 'NM', 'DB')` you would get your desired output using `cumsum(x == 'NM')` Does this help with your real data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `cumsum`:

```
df$group = cumsum(df$starts_with == "NM")
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't ever heard of this function in my searching. Thank you!